# Are Masterplan projects equivalent to adventures or campaigns?

Tags: campaign-development, tools, masterplan

I started using Masterplan last time I DMed and I love what the tool brings to the table.  However, I'm not certain how to use it to track my entire campaign.

Does a Masterplan adventure project represent an entire campaign, with plot points representing adventures and sub-plots representing the details of those adventures?

Or am I supposed to make a new adventure project for every distinct adventure I design (adventures defined as having a distinct start and end but could span multiple sessions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Masterplan is meant to be used for both**

From the [Masterplan](http://web.archive.org/web/20160720091339/http://masterplan.habitualindolence.net:80/) front page *(now defunct)*:

> When you're preparing a D&D 4E game, what do you need to do?
>
> ```
> Organise your plot?
> Detail the campaign world?
> Create interesting, balanced encounters?
> Build dungeon maps?
> Design engaging skill challenges?
> Distribute level-appropriate treasure parcels?
> Create stats for custom creatures?
> Create campaign-specific game mechanics?
> ```
>
> Whatever your answer, Masterplan helps with that.

The Plot flowchart can be used for both single adventures and long-term plots. It may be easier to create a master/high-level plotchart for the campaign and then individual adventure plot flowcharts than to try to keep track of it all together in one plot flowchart.

Comment: Now would you create those separate plot flowcharts in one single adventure project, or in separate adventure projects?  (the "adventure project" is basically the file everything is saved to)

Comment: I would create them in the same file just for housekeeping purposes, You can have more than one plot flowchart in an adventure project, right? (I don't have as much experience with Masterplan as I would like since I was trying to use it to run 4e encounters and it didn't support as well as inCombat through iPlay4e did.

Comment: I ended up using the subplot feature to make the different adventures as different subplots in the adventure project so that it's all together. inCombat works nicely, too.